How to programmatically create a new tabpanel in tabview?
Angular 18.
In response to a menu click, I've dynamically created a component using createComponent.  Now I'd like to create a new tabpanel in my tabview and display the above new component in that new tab.
I've searched and found this example: Dynamically Add tabPanel to tabView in PrimeNg
However, the above link example references code where the TabPanel constructor takes 1 OR 3 parameters.   The version of primeng I have now is expecting 4 parameters with an ElementRef being the new 2nd parameter. What am I suppose to pass in for this?
Is there any online example of how to programmatically add a new tab using the latest angular 18 standalone components and primeng?
